# Restoring Matplotlib default styles using `with`

Tags: matplotlib, with-statement

I would like to be able to temporarily used arbitrary staples for my Matplotlib plot using the idiom

```
with my_styles(style):
    # plotting code ...
```

and have defined

```
def my_styles(style='mine'):
    if style == 'mine':
        return plt.rc_context({
            "font.family": "sans-serif", 
            "mathtext.fontset": "dejavusans", 
            "font.sans-serif": ["Nunito", "Open Sans"] + plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"],
            "text.usetex": False })
    elif style == 'another': 
        # USE - Very slow (?)
        return plt.rc_context({
            'axes.linewidth': 1.5,
            'lines.linewidth': 2.0,
            'figure.facecolor': 'white',
            'grid.linewidth': 0.0,
            'axes.grid': False,
            'axes.unicode_minus': False,
            'axes.edgecolor': 'black',
            'text.usetex': True
        })
    else:
        return plt.rc_context(plt.rc_params())
```

But the final case does not restore Matplotlib's default styles, and instead appears to continue to use styles previously used. How do I completely restore Matplotlib's defaults, and what is the correct idiom for doing so using `rc_context` and `with`?

Comment: [`rc_file_defaults`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_file_defaults) might help

Comment: @tmdavison Elaborate. That’s what a previous version had.